# Mocking data in Playwright

Tags: mocking, nestjs, prisma, e2e-testing, playwright

I have been learning End-to-End (E2E) testing through Playwright within the context of my Nest.Js project. I am accustomed to write unit tests using Jest, a framework that facilitates the mocking of Prisma and other injectable dependencies. I am curious whether it is viable to replicate the Prisma mocking approach within Playwright's E2E testing framework, or whether such emulation is even requisite in an E2E context.

```
test.describe('isolate user test', () => {
    test('isolated test', async({page}) => {
        await page.evaluate(() => {
            (window as any).fetch = async (url: string) => {
              return new Response(JSON.stringify({ key: 'mocked-value' }));
            };
        });
    
        await page.goto('https://google.com');
    });
});
```

I am curious whether it is viable to replicate the Prisma mocking approach within Playwright's E2E testing framework, or whether such emulation is even requisite in an E2E context. If possible please attach link for reference.

Comment: Late reply here, but mocking is, in my humble opinion, not something that is fitting for an e2e test, unless a third party integration is at play. It does not test the real service so its best left to more granular functional testing. The idiom I recommend is that an e2e test should test what a user does